# My cat has a wormy eye discharge

Tags: cats, diseases, eye-disease

I have 2 cats in my house, both Ragdolls, age 6-7 months each.
The older one of the two has recurring eye discharge which you can see in the images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m47Kx.jpg .

Video: https://streamable.com/ql1t3

First he had this issue with the right eye, after treatment with Aureomycin (chlortetracycline hydrochloride 10mg/g) for 5 days (morning and evening) it passed.

I think at that treatment both cats got treatment for 10 days for herpes as well.

But then it started in the left eye, he had 1 treatment that made it go away for a week, then it came again. Now after the second treatment (of the left eye) it's back again.

I've been to the vet, he gave me the Aureomycin, so before going back to the vet I could use any help to understand what he got and why it keeps getting back.

Comment: What are other symptoms? Does he have nose discharge, saliva discharge (drooling), loss of appetite or fever?

Comment: Has your vet conducted any lab test? Is your cat is of general weak health and earlier also suffered from other diseases?

Comment: hi @Sonevol, sorry for the late reply, no nose discharge or saliva, great appetite, no fever. Healthy cat and no known other diseases. Cat had blood tests but nothing extreme was found.

Comment: It's been a month, how is your kitten now? Still dealing with the discharge? Any other treatments?

Comment: @elbrant well 3 weeks ago we took him to the vet for ear treatment (allot of brown stuff in the ears) + a week of ear drops, on the same time we also switched food. and after a few days it was down to a normal cat eye discharge. not sure if it was the ear issue or maybe the food gave him allergy.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something as simple as an ingrown eyelash, but often times it's conjunctivitis, which is probably what the vet assumes. The vet should do a thorough eye exam (both eyes) for a root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should bring the cat back to the vet because if the cat is still getting this infection the cat should be further examined. Also at home are you keeping the cat litter clean and keeping its environment clean and animals around it are clean etc. I also express letting your cat get some air by letting it outside on a leash or whatever your comfortable with to ensure the cat gets some oxygen.